# How to display django-simple-history in template from a views.py or other?

Tags: django

I do not know how to display a history in a Django template, nor even how to use it in the Django `views.py`:

**`views.py:`**

```
class Fournisseur(models.Model):
    photo = models.FileField(verbose_name="Photo")
    nom_f = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Fournisseur")
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Adresse")
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Courriel")
    contact = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Contact")
    date_f = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date de création")
    history = HistoricalRecords()

def __str__(self):
    return self.nom_f
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

in views.py

```
def some_view(request, pk):
    if request.method == "GET":
       obj = Fournisseur.objects.get(pk=pk)
       return render(request, 'template.html', context={'object': obj})
```

in template.html:

```
{% for h in object.history.all %}
   {{ h }}  // history object
   {{ h.changed_by }}
   {{ h.comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

For details please see in [documentation](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#querying-history)

Comment: Can you help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477320/how-to-change-automatically-django-formset-with-each-iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
def some_view(request, pk):
if request.method == "GET":
   obj = Fournisseur.objects.get(pk=pk)
   return render(request, 'template.html', context={'object': obj})


{% for h in object.history.all %}
   {{ h }}  // history object
   {{ h.history_object }} // the object of the model
   {{ h.history_date }}  // the date of history
   {{ h.history_user }}  // Changed by, the user
{% endfor %}
```